# How to set Initial value to a TextFormField on value received from previous screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my react native project, I have a list of data in one page. Then on click of each card from the list I go to the details page of them by passing the values of that pressed card like below code-

```
Navigator.pushNamed(ctxt, '/DetailsNotes', arguments: _allNotes[index]);
```

After that, in the next screen I receive the value inside the build function like below way-

```
final ModelAllNotes args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

In this screen I have two **TextFormField** and initialized them inside build function like below-

```
final title = TextFormField(
  controller: _textFieldControllerTitle,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  autofocus: false,
  maxLength: 100,

  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Title',
    labelText: 'Title',

    icon: Icon(selectedIcons),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
  ),


  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },

  onSaved: (String value) {
    this._data.title = value;
  },

);
```

I have also declared the **controlller** to handle text changing and saving issue of **TextFormField** like below-

```
   TextEditingController _textFieldControllerTitle = TextEditingController();
```

So, now the problem is-

I want to have the initial values of the **TextFormField** from the value received in args variable and then allow user to edit the TextformFields. But whenever I am using the **initialValue** property to each **TextFormField** it is not working.

I need a solution to have the received value from args( from previous screen) and then show them initially in my **TextFromField** and keep them editable.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use [`TextEditingController.fromValue(...)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/TextEditingController.fromValue.html):

```
TextFormField(
  controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
    TextEditingValue(
      text: arg,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: arg.length,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can make it more complex/useful by hooking up various listeners and whatnot to retrieve or/and manipulate the values.

To see it in action, I've added a minimal runnable example below. Your case will probably need a bit more code (perhaps `dispose` and more robust `offset` handling), as it's only for illustration purposes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Editable());
}

class Editable extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('First Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('To editable screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second', arguments: 'some value');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String value = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Second Screen")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
                TextEditingValue(
                  text: value,
                  selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: value.length),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Back'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class ... extends State<...>{
TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final arg = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    controller.text = arg;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```